# grails scaffolding and tfs file locking

Tags: git, grails, tfs

After checking in Grails artifacts into Team Foundation Server (TFS), all artefacts get locked and further scaffolding fails, such as running generate-all against a domain for which artefacts had been previously checked in. This is really painful. We have thus far been checking out the entire project before doing more work, but this causes other problems. Is there some way to better manage this? I am a newbie to TFS.

**--Edit #1 --**

When I speak of locking, I am referring to the local files being write protected.

**-- Edit #2 --**

I suppose I could use git-tfs or git-tf (not sure which is really better), possibly svnbridge, but I am hoping for a simpler solution for my team. Most have worked with TFS only and the requirement to bring in a new version control system may scuttle the whole Grails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a prebuild event to your affected projects. Right click on the project and select properties under the build events tab you can enter command line code to do the check out against the affected files.
Depending on how you have your configurations set up for your solution you may be better to unload the project and then type in directly to the .csproj file so that you can get the prebuild event to fire for all configurations.

Only your scaffolding files should be targeted, this way when you get latest and perform a build your scaffolding files will be checked out, when you come to do a check in the checked out files will be compared and if no chages were made to the scaffolding, then the checkin will be ignored as there are no changes.

In your solution identify your project with the grails scaffolding

[image: Solution Structure]

If you right click the project and select properties, then go to the Build Events tab

[image: Project Properties]

You can enter scripts here for pre or post build, but typing directly into the project xml gives you more flexibility.

Unload the project so that you can edit the project xml directly
[image: Unload Project]

Then right click again and select edit Project.CSProj

[image: Edit Proj file]

Scroll down to the bottom of the Project file xml, here you will find the pre and post build sections. The condition statement should be set to meet your needs, here I'm assuming that release is only used by the build, so the code will only be fired if the configuration is not equal to Release.

[image]

Uncomment the prebuild section and add the code that you want to fire prior to the code being compiled. This is only an example you may have to expand the paths to the files depending on how your project is structured.

```
      <!--To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.--> 
  <!--Target for prebuild event when the configuration is not Release-->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Release' " >
    <!--Recursively check out everything in the sub folder-->
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe checkout Scaffolding /recursive
    <!--Check out a list of individual files-->
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe checkout Scaffoldingfile1.cs Scaffoldingfile2.cs
  </Target>
```

You can then close the Project file and reload in visual studio.

Your process should now be

- Get Latest Code from source control
- Rebuild the Solution
- Your scaffolding code should be automatically checked out
- Make any changes to the solution
- Perform the check in

At check in if your scaffolding files have been updated they should be checked in, if no changes have occurred TFS should ignore the files and undo the check out.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. Please share such syntax. Not sure that I fully comprehend your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks much. I doubt that I will implement it, though it seems the right solution. It appears we will be moving to Mercurial shortly and this will become a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TFS 2012 or newer you can use what's called a Local workspace (as opposed to a Server Workspace).  This will stop TFS from making your files read-only.

It should be the default workspace type in TFS 2012+, but you can check by clicking the Workspaces drop-down in Source Control Explorer, choose Workspaces... then edit your workspace, click Advanced, and check if your workspace type is set to Local.

Comment: I am using TFS 2010, sadly.